# Some trigonometric integral

Tags: calculus

This is not a standard calculus exercise in the sense that I found these relations quite indirectly, but I'd like to see direct (computational) proofs of the following, unfortunately my calculus skills have seen better days !

Fix a positive integer $q\ge 1$. Define $$F_0(\theta)=1$$ and for integer $n\ge 1$, $$ F_n(\theta) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{q(q+1)}}\left(2\cos n\theta + (q-1)\frac{\sin[(n+1)\theta]}{\sin \theta}\right).$$

Then for any $k,r\ge 0$,
$$ \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^\pi F_k(\theta)F_r(\theta)\frac{4q(q+1)\sin^2\theta}{(q+1)^2-4q\cos^2\theta}d\theta = \begin{cases} 1& \text{if } r=k,\\0& \text{if } r\neq k.\end{cases}$$

You may assume $q\ge 2$ since the case $q=1$ is simple.

edit : if the task seems overwhelming, how about the case $r=k=0$ ? should be simple enough..

Comment: For the definition of $F_n(\theta)$, is that $\sin((n+1)\theta)$?

Comment: yes, it's as you say.

Comment: I edited that (only).

Comment: Not sure how much this helps but $\frac{\sin((n+1)\theta)}{\sin\theta}=U_n(\cos\theta)$ with $U_n$ being the [Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevPolynomialoftheSecondKind.html). There are some nice known recurrences of these polynomials.

Comment: Yes I know, $F_n$ is a linear combination of Chebyshev polynomials of first and second kinds. Each family ($T_n$ or $U_n$) forms a complete system of orthogonal polynomials with distinct weight, here there is a common weight for this particular combination. It's funny the way this relation appeared has nothing to do with calculus or orthogonal polynomial theory.